# MVC Razor Shared external layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor

I'm looking for a way to reference a shared external _layout.cshtml from MVC 3 and Razor.

A little back story:
We have multiple developers. All of them are working on separate MVC applications that all need the same look and feel. All these applications will be deployed to the same site for example
http://www.example.com/App1/
and
http://www.example.com/App2/

The look and feel will be generated by the CMS and dropped into a different folder
http://www.example.com/Layout/_layoutExt.cshtml

I've tried

```
MasterName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\layout\_LayoutExt.cshtml";
```

But it gives me the error that it can't find the file

> The view 'Index' or its master was not
>   found or no view engine supports the
>   searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My eventual solution was to use Symbolic links (or junctions or hard links) to link the needed file into the view folder. This way the CMS writes to one location and my app reads from another. Not the clean solution I was looking for.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I need to do the same thing but am not quite sure what your solution is.  What's a symbolic link?  How do you reference the layout file in Visual Studio project?  Do you copy it in pre-build?  Did you play around with precompiling the layout into a dll and referencing that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For development I use a separate layout from live. On live I eventually switched to creating a virtual directory in IIS. so for example I point my layout at cms/_layoutfile.cshtml but there is no cms folder in my project. I use IIS to create a cms virtual folder under views after I deploy. I point this folder somewhere on my hard drive where I know the real layout file can be found. When MVC looks for the file it will follow this virtual folder and find the shared layout file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to make your own view engine that support reading file outside the web application home directory.